# How to create login and signup actions in yii2 API

Tags: api, yii2

I am working on yii2 api and want to create the user login and user register/signup,but I don't know how to create the login and signup in API

I can GET the values from User, but how the login and signup will work when yii2 will work with iOS application?

this is my code for user controller,

```
namespace api\modules\v1\controllers;
use Yii;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use yii\rest\ActiveController;
use api\modules\v1\models\User; 
use yii\web\Response;
use yii\web\JsonResponseFormatter;

/**
 * UserController implements the CRUD actions for User model.
 */
class UserController extends ActiveController
{
  public function behaviors(){
                $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
                $behaviors['bootstrap'] = [
                'class' => \yii\filters\ContentNegotiator::className(),
                'formats' => [
                    'application/json' => Response::FORMAT_JSON,
                ],               
            ];
                return $behaviors;
        }


    public $modelClass = 'api\modules\v1\models\User';   

   public function actionUserapi()
    {
        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
         return new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => User::find()->asArray()
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Registration**

```
/**
 * Signs user up.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new SignupForm();
    $params = Yii::$app->request->post();
    $model->username = $params['username'];
    $model->password=$params['password'];
    $model->email=$params['email'];

    if ($model->signup()) {
  $response['isSuccess'] = 201;
  $response['message'] = 'You are now a member!';
  $response['user'] =\common\models\User::findByUsername($model->username);
        return $response;   
        }
  else {
  //$model->validate();
  $model->getErrors();
  $response['hasErrors'] = $model->hasErrors();
  $response['errors'] = $model->getErrors();
            //return = $model;
          return $response;

        }
}
```

**Login**

```
  /**
 * User login.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
 public function actionLogin(){
    $model = new LoginForm();
    $params = Yii::$app->request->post();
    $model->username = $params['username'];
    $model->password = $params['password'];
    if ($model->login()) {
        $response['message'] = 'You are now logged in!';
        $response['user'] = \common\models\User::findByUsername($model->username);
        //return [$response,$model];  
        return $response; 
        }
    else {
          $model->validate();
          $response['errors'] = $model->getErrors();
            return $response;
        }
}
```

Comment: If you are promoting your own web site, you need to be explicit about it.  Please see [how not to be a spammer](/help/promotion).

Comment: @tripleee Understood